# How to avoid MissingBackpressureException when using Observable#observeOn?

Tags: java, rx-java

**Background:** I have an application in which I am iterating through all users in the following way:

```
Observable<User> allUsers = fetchAllUsers();
allUsers
    .filter(new MyUserFilter())
    .flatMap(new UserItemFetcher()) // Expand into stuff I'm interested in.
    .filter(new MyItemFilter())
    .forEach(new UserItemHandler());
```

Each `UserItemHandler` execution was a bit slow so I wanted to use a thread pool for the handling:

```
ExecutorService threadPool = ...;
Observable<User> allUsers = fetchAllUsers();
allUsers
    .filter(new MyUserFilter())
    .flatMap(new UserItemFetcher())
    .filter(new MyItemFilter())
    .forEach(new UserItemHandler(threadPool));
gracefulShutdownOf(threadPool);
```

where

- the `UserItemHandler` delegates work to be done to `threadPool`; and
- `threadPool` has a

  - queue with an upper bound to avoid filling up too many items in memory; and
  - `RejectedExecutionHandler` that blocks until the queue has an available spot.

However, in the best of worlds I didn't want developers having to deal with an `ExeccutorService` when working with `UserItemHandler`, so I refactored into

```
ExecutorService threadPool = ...;
Observable<User> allUsers = fetchAllUsers();
allUsers
    .observeOn(Schedulers.from(threadPool))
    .filter(new MyUserFilter())
    .flatMap(new UserItemFetcher())
    .filter(new MyItemFilter())
    .forEach(new UserItemHandler());
gracefulShutdownOf(threadPool);
```

**Problem:** `OperatorObserveOn` throws `MissingBackpressureException` whenever I run the above application.

**Questions:**

1. What is best practise to avoid `MissingBackpressureException` without 1) [buffering all items into memory](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#onBackpressureBuffer()) nor 2) [dropping items](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#onBackpressureDrop())? I can't miss any items.
2. As a workaround, I essentially implemented [my own simple `observeOn`](https://gist.github.com/JensRantil/9d5296f67c32988c41e6b58b03e21252). I've been skimming then implementation of `OperatorObserveOn`, and it's really complex. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What is your `fetchAllUsers()` doing? I presume you wrote it with `create()` but didn't implement backpressure for it?

Comment: It is actually, a `create().flatMap()`. I didn't know I could make create handle backpressure. Do you have any reference on how to do that? Does flatMap handle backpressure?

Comment: Why did you use `create()`? Do you bridge some legacy callback API?

Comment: Because it allowed me to page through a resultset larger than can be loaded into memory.

Comment: Could you post how fetchAllUsers() looks like. Perhaps existing operators can work for you as well as provide backpressure.

Comment: I revisited the `create()` and I was wrong - it didn't use `create().flatMap()`. Here's a snippet of the code: https://gist.github.com/JensRantil/822fccc1eba9cd74907b4855e1f77513/86c2f044ecc5dc693e05def3500a1baa2258ac41 Essentially it fetches a range of prefixes for users. AFAIK, `Observable#from` seem to gracefully handle backpressure, would something like revision 3 in https://gist.github.com/JensRantil/822fccc1eba9cd74907b4855e1f77513/revisions handle backpressure?

Comment: If you use standard operators such as `from()` and `flatMapIterable`, backpressure is handled for you.

Comment: Rewriting the producer to use common operators fixed it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37363873/how-to-avoid-missingbackpressureexception-when-using-observableobserveon?noredirect=1#comment62270197_37363873.